# Jesus Praying before working a miracle

Tags: jesus

why did Jesus Pray before working miracles Ex. Changing water into wine, Raising Lazarus from dead, while he din't in other Occasions ex. Waking on the Water, Healing the sick, Lepers, lame and blind. What was necessary for him to pray to God to work a miracle when he is God himself?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  You should include some explicit Bible references in the question to facilitate an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made an interesting observation regarding Jesus’ miracles and why he prayed on some occasions and not on others.

The account of Jesus turning water into wine (John 2:1-11) does not mention that Jesus prayed before performing the miracle.  Likewise, when Jesus calmed the storm (Matthew 8, Mark 4, and Luke 8) there is no mention of Jesus praying.  After Jesus fed the five thousand men (plus women and children) with five loaves and two fish (Matthew 14:13-21), is the miracle of Jesus walking on the water (Matthew 14:22-27):

> “Immediately he made the disciples get into the boat and go before him to the other side, while he dismissed the crowds. And after he had dismissed the crowds, he went up on the mountain by himself to pray. When evening came, he was there alone, but the boat by this time was a long way from the land, beaten by the waves, for the wind was against them.  And in the fourth watch of the night he came to them, walking on the sea.  But when the disciples saw him walking on the sea, they were terrified, and said, “It is a ghost!” and they cried out in fear. But immediately Jesus spoke to them, saying, “Take heart; it is I. Do not be afraid.”

The Bible tells us that Jesus prayed in a variety of settings, both public and private. He prayed in times of joy and times of sorrow. He prayed for Himself, and He prayed for others. He prayed to express thanks, to petition for needs, and to commune with His Father.  Prayer was an integral part of Jesus’ time on earth, and He prayed regularly: “Jesus often withdrew to lonely places and prayed” (Luke 5:16).  Jesus also prayed at His baptism (Luke 3:21–22); before feeding the 5,000 (Luke 9:16) and the 4,000 (Matthew 15:36); and at the moment of His transfiguration (Luke 9:29). Before Jesus chose His twelve disciples, He “spent the night praying to God” on a mountainside (Luke 6:12).

Jesus prayed at Lazarus’ tomb. As they rolled away the stone from His friend’s tomb, “Jesus looked up and said, ‘Father, I thank you that you have heard me. I knew that you always hear me, but I said this for the benefit of the people standing here, that they may believe that you sent me’” (John 11:41–42). This is a good example of prayer prayed in the hearing of others for the sake of the hearers.

Praise was a regular part of Jesus’ prayers.  Jesus’ relationship with His heavenly Father naturally resulted in His desire to spend time communicating with Him.  Another important aspect of Jesus’ prayers was His submission to the Father. His prayers were always in accordance with God’s will.

It is important to understand that before Jesus came to earth to dwell with us, he had existed in heaven from eternity alongside the Father and the Holy Spirit.  The apostle John explains it thus:

> ”In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.  He was with God in the beginning.  Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made... The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us.  We have seen his glory, the glory of the One and Only, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth” (John 1:1-3, 14).

So why, you ask, was it necessary for him to pray to God to work a miracle when he is God himself?  Here is a brief extract from an article that answers this question:

> When Jesus, the eternal Son of God, took upon Himself sinless humanity He also took on the form of a servant, giving up His heavenly glory (Philippians 2:5-11). As the God-man, He had to learn obedience (Hebrews 5:8) to His Father as He was tempted by Satan, accused falsely by men, rejected by His people, and eventually crucified. His praying to His heavenly Father was to ask for power (John 11:41-42) and wisdom (Mark 1:35, 6:46). His praying showed His dependence upon His Father in His humanity to carry out His Father's plan of redemption, as evidenced in Christ's high priestly prayer in John 17. His praying demonstrated that He ultimately submitted to His Father's will, which was to go to the cross and pay the penalty (death) for our breaking God's law (Matthew 26:31-46).  Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-pray-God.html

God the Son always acted in complete harmony with God the Father.  The Father sent the Son and the Son came to earth to do the will of his Father.  Throughout his earthly life, Jesus kept in close contact with his heavenly Father through prayer.  A bit like sending text messages between people who are separated by great physical distances – you send the prayer up, it is received and then the response is bounced back down.  Great way to keep in touch with your nearest and dearest!

Comment: Excellent Answer, +1.  We should not assume that the Gospels record all details - it is quite probable that Jesus prayed far more often than is recorded; so we cannot know that Jesus did not pray before each miracle.  I personally suspect that because Jesus was so close to the Father, that they existed in a kind of continuous prayer.

Answer (score 0):

Your last few word show the problem.  Prayer is an act of worship among other things, so to speak.   So the point you make is very valid!   Jesus said:-

> NWT Matthew 26:42  "“**My Father,** if it is not possible for this to pass away unless I drink it, ***let your will*** take place.”
>
> NWT Hebrews 10:7  "Then I said: ‘Look! I have come (in the scroll it is written about me) to do your will, O God.’. . ."

Jesus had to appeal to God for his power to do as God wanted him to do:-

> NWT  John 4:34 "Jesus said to them: “My food is ***to do the will of him who sent me and to finish HIS work..***

So his spoken prayers were to show he was doing God's will to bring people back to worship the God he worshiped.

> NWT Mk 15:34 "Jesus called out with a loud voice: “Eʹli, Eʹli, laʹma sa·bach·thaʹni?” which means, when translated: “***My God, my God..."***